# Mysqli: Select from table where field equals field from other table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables, one is "words" and one is "synonyms". In words, I would have something like:

```
word_id     word
1           apple
2           funny
```

In synonyms, it would look like:

```
word_id     synonym
2           hilarious
2           amusing
```

I am trying to make a query that will pull all of the synonyms for a word, so when I search for the word "funny", it will pull all the records in the synonyms table with word_id of 2.

So, to break it down, select word_id from words where word = search term, then select * from synonyms where word_id = word_id from the words table.

How do I perform this query? I'm assuming something with LEFT JOIN, but I don't know much about queries when they start getting advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), here is an example:

```
SELECT words.word, synonyms.synonym
FROM words
LEFT JOIN synonyms
ON words.word_id=synonyms.word_id
WHERE words.word_id = ?
```

Check the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to learn more about the syntax

Comment: Thank you, but all I get for a result is: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) ` I'm looking to get an array of all the actual synonym word names.

Comment: @JROB the relationship is the `word_id` you need to get that first after typing the word

Comment: So, this will need two queries then?

Comment: ... one query to find the word_id, then the second query as in your example?

Comment: @JROB yes exactly, if your note sure you can share the php code, and I will help you with it

Answer (score 0):

To complete such a query you will need to use `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM words LEFT JOIN synonyms 
ON words.word_id = synonyms.word_id
WHERE words.word_id = 2
```

In this case we are assuming 2 is the word_id
you can check out the reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for more clarification

Comment: Thanks, but when I perform the search, I will be searching using the actual word. The word id is unknown.

Comment: Then the where clause should be `WHERE words.word LIKE % $word %` $word will be the value passed from the search

Comment: Yes, I updated your query. Thank you. The problem is that I am just getting back: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 112 [type] => 0 )` I'm not getting an array of actual synonym words.